# What is the correct way to force an app to core dump and quit?

Tags: c++, c, signals, coredump

I just came across some code which used the kill system call to send a SIGSEGV signal to an app. The rationale behind this was that this would force the app to core dump and quit. This seems so wrong to me, is this normal practice?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11185/dump-process-core-without-killing-the-process/11191#11191

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SIGQUIT is the correct signal to send to a program if you wish to produce a core dump. `kill` is the correct command line program to send signals (it is of course poorly named, since not all signals will kill the program).

Note, you should not send random signals to the program, not all of them will produce a core dump. Many of them will be handled by the program itself, either consumed, ignored, or induce other processing. Thus sending a SIGSEGV is wrong.

---

GCC Says:
http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html

POSIX/Unix Says:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/signal.h.html

Comment: +1 but a reference would go a long way here… what does POSIX actually say about core dumps?

Comment: Okay. Second doc marks with 'A' meaning abort and may produce a core file.

Comment: Unfortunately, the application could have installed a signal handler for SIGQUIT preventing the default behaviour. In this case, you won't get a core dump any more. Would you then - and only then - consider it legitimate to try to abuse one of the other signals by default generating a core dump (SIGSEGV, SIGILL, ...)?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. `kill` is somewhat misnamed -- it can send any signal. There are many uses for `kill` which don't result in the process being killed at all!

Comment: +1:  kill -1 is commonly used to send SIGHUP, which traditionally causes programs written with this functionality to reload their configurations.  (e.g.: sendmail, init, etc.)

Comment: SIGQUIT being the one to get a core dump.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make an application dump it's core from another program, pretty much the only way to do it is via a signal. SEGV would be fine for this. Alternatively you can hook a debugger up to the program and freeze it and view it's registers and such without killing it.

If you want to dump a core from within an application there are nicer ways to do it, like via an assert().

So, no, it's not particularly wrong to send a SEGV to a program. You could also send things like SIGILL for illegal instruction, or a divide by zero signal. It's all fine.

Comment: No, it's not fine. These signals all have specific meanings and programs respond to them differently. They won't all kill the program, nor will they all produce core dumps.

Answer (score 3):

The way to do it in Unix/Linux is to call abort() which will send SIGABORT to current process. The other option is raise() where you can specify what signal you want to send to current process.

Comment: +1 for `raise` and `abort` which make a lot more sense when the target is yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Richard Stevens (_Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment) wrote:

> The generation of core is an implementation features of most Unix. It is not part of POSIX.1.

He lists 12 signals whose default action is to terminate with a core (ANSI: SIGABRT, SIGFPE, SIGILL, SIGSEGV, POSIX: SIGQUIT, Other: SIGBUS, SIGEMT, SIGIOT, SIGSYS, SIGTRAP, SIGXCPU, SIGXFSZ), all of them are overwritable (the two signals which aren't overwritable are SIGKILL and SIGSTOP).

I've never seen a way to generate a core which isn't the use of a default signal handler.

So if your goal is to generate a core and stop, the best is to choose a signal whose default handler does the job (SIGSEGV does the job), reset the default handler for the signal if you are using it and then use kill.

Comment: Emacs has a way to generate a core without a signal handler. It's used in the program's build process to save a new emacs binary with the elisp already loaded, and it's a horrible hack...

Comment: @R.. Last time I checked, emacs way was to write a core file all by itself by having knowledge of the executable and core file formats.

Comment: Yes, that's what it does. XEmacs has a much saner approach - it allocates all the elisp code/data into a heap it manages itself (in the `.data` section), saves that to disk, and then at runtime uses `mmap` with `MAP_FIXED` to map that back over top of its "heap".