# Force kernel to dump a process when SIGSEGV is hooked

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, segmentation-fault

I write the application for a system with very limited RAM value. As application crash is always possible and it uses dynamic memory allocation, I created callbacks for all possible ways application can be stopped and clean up all buffers there, like so:

```
sigaddset ( &sigact.sa_mask, SIGSEGV );
sigaction ( SIGSEGV, &sigact, ( struct sigaction* ) NULL );
```

It triggers some notifying actions and tries to restart itself several times.
But still I want to know what caused the crash, so I need crashdump. GDB is no go for such a small system and only kernel level core dump is possible.
But as application intercepted such a signal and after all exits by itself, kernel doesn't receive signal  -no core is created.
I can't issue

```
 kill(getpid(), kernel_signal);
```

As it leads to recursion - this signal also intercepted. Is it possible at all in such a situation?

Comment: The [`abort`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/abort.3.html) function might help, unless you catch `SIGABRT` too (which you shouldn't).

Comment: Have you tried `SIGQUIT`? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5648539/464709) mentions it as the correct way to force a core dump. Alternately, [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11191) on [unix.se] suggests forking the process and having the child abort immediately. It may also work in your situation.

Comment: SIGQUIT for some reason doesn't trigger core creation but SIGABRT does. Joachim, please make your comment as answer - it is correct. I tested it and it does all I wanted

Comment: `"I created callbacks for all possible ways application can be stopped and clean up all buffers there"` What's the point? All resources are automatically reclaimed by the kernel when a process exits for any reason.

Comment: Yes, but I mostly meant to clearly finish work with devices and their buffers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps instead of a core dump you can print out a backtrace. That should use less memory and is a catchable signal. Please see this signal handler.

```
#include <execinfo.h>

/* This signal handler ensures clean exits while not running in daemon mode */
void signal_handler(int type)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "\nSIGNAL CAUGHT: %d: ", type);

    switch (type)
    {
    case SIGSEGV:
        {
#ifdef GLIBC
            {
                void *array[10];
                size_t size;

                // get void*'s for all entries on the stack
                size = backtrace(array, 10);

                // print out all the frames to stderr
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: signal %d:\n", type);
                backtrace_symbols_fd(array, size, STDERR_FILENO);

                // DO CLEANUP HERE
            }
#else // Cause ulibc is terrible
            fprintf(stderr, "SEGMENTATION FAULT");

            // DO CLEANUP HERE

            break;
        }
#endif
    case SIGINT:
    case SIGTERM:
    case SIGHUP:
    default:
        {
          // DO CLEANUP HERE
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Just beautiful! How many things else should I find out about C? :)

Comment: Just wanted to add, that in order to make function names recognized by backtrace, program should be compiled with -rdynamic option (GCC). By default it takes name from dynamic linkage table. To force it use all function - we need that option