# Controlled crash in C++ builder (to practice debugging iOS FireMonkey apps)

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I'd like to experiment with symbolicating after a crash.  I'm building my app in C++ Builder 10.2.3 (Tokyo).  How can i cause a crash intentionally in code - in a controlled manner.

thanks,
russ

Comment: What do you mean by controlled crash?  Do you want to be able to trigger a crash at will, or just have a way to crash a program at the same point in your program every time?

Comment: its unclear what you are wanting and not sure what platform you're using but [forcing a core dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648172/what-is-the-correct-way-to-force-an-app-to-core-dump-and-quit) might be a thing you can do

Comment: I just want to cause my code to crash so i can practice debugging of my iOS app.

Comment: I looked at "abort" but it doesn't look to be supported for iOS.  [Embarcadero abort](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Assert)

Comment: SIGKILL [looks like](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html) it would fit the bill but after reading about [raise](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/devwin32/raise_xml.html) in the Embarcadero docs it doesn't look FireMonkey friendly.